# Accessing SalesForce custom object Issue

Tags: asp.net, salesforce

I am trying to call my Salesforce custom object with c#. Name of the object is `CommercientSF__SorMasterRep__c` but when i try to upsert into it gives me error like

> INVALID_TYPE: sObject type `'CommercientSF__SorMasterRep__c'` is not
>   supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to
>   append the `'__c'` after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or
>   the describe call for the appropriate names.

It is coming from a managed package. The package is installed & all objects are deployed.

Comment: You could use a separate tool with the same login credentials to verify access to your custom object via the API. There are a number of options at [http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Tools](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Tools). Try the Force.com Explorer or Workbench. If non of those suit, there are a number of third party options too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wsdl may not have your custom-object (CommercientSF_SorMasterRep__c) included during generation. Verify if Your wsdl has this custom object. 
If not, regenerate wsdl again and import into your C# project.

Answer (score 1):

The name of a custom objects ends with __c (underscore, underscore, 'c'), looks like you only have one underscore in your object name.

For managed packages the object is only available if the user is assigned a license for the package, you should also check the object level permissions in the users profile. Also see the section "[Factors that affect data access](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/calls.htm#sforce_api_calls_concepts_factors)" in the docs.

Comment: there are two underscores in object name.

Comment: Object is also deployed in Salesforce

Comment: that's not what your question has. Also list the things you already checked.

Comment: License is also active for the user & permission is also clear for that

Comment: Superfell if you'll hit "edit" on this question you'll realize it's Markdown formatting engine playing tricks on you ;) Actually I'm going to edit the question right away...